# In Rails how to handle dynamic color changes based on users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So we have seven directors that are getting their own show page. I'm trying to determine the best, most clean, way of handling a section on the show page that has a block of color and a link to their department. So far I've come up with two options.

Option 1 - CSS and Conditional Statements

```
<% if @user.id == 5 %>
 <div id="bill-franklin">
   CONTENT
<% elsif @user.id == 6 %>
 <div id="joan-smith">
   CONTENT
```

Then all the styling based on ids in CSS. Clunky but works.

Option 2 - Apply the color to the db and place that in the code.

```
<div class="<%= @user.color %>" >
  CONTENT
</div>
```

Is there another option that is cleaner than option 1 and doesn't involve me adding to the db like 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an unlimited amount of users you'll need to add some configuration on the database. If you don't, you can create css classes based on user data. For example:

```
<div class="my_user_<%= @user.id %>" >
  CONTENT
</div>
```

Now, in your css file you can do:

```
.my_user_1 { background-color: red; }
.my_user_2 { background-color: blue; }
```

> It would be nice to use something better than the user id to build the custom classes

Comment: nice, this will work to `<div class="my_user_#{@user.id}" >`

Comment: This is bad also because adding director means that you need to update CSS. And I bet, at some point, you'd want to do that from the UI. I'd go with DB solution, even though it means that you store styling in the DB.

Comment: I tried not to guess thats why I said: "If you have an unlimited amount of users you'll need to add some configuration on the database". Also, if he can make conditions using the user id, the solution I gave is adjusted.

Comment: Yeah I have seven directors so I'm not too concerned here. I like the idea a lot. Now it's an issue that we're using Slim.

Answer (score 0):

you can use their first name to create classes or as per your current table structure

```
.bill {background-color: 'red';}
.joan {background-color: 'yellow';}
```

use in view like

```
<div class="#{@user.firstname}"> #or whatever field you like to use
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I honestly really like this. The problem is getting this to work in Slim because ##{@user.id} does not work nor does .#{@user.id}

Comment: I don't use slim, but i think this should work `div class="#{@user.id}"`

Comment: it's class='#{@user.id}' for future reference